# comparing nil to integer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, compare, null

In the following case where `string` is an `NSString`

```
if (string.length < 1)
{
    return;
}
```

and `string` turns out to be `nil` the `if` statement will still evaluate correctly because in this case `nil` evaluates to `0`.

However, is this recommended practice (by Clang or Apple) and are there any arguments against this and doing something closer to:

```
if (!string || string.length < 1)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to enter in the if block if string is nil, that code is not correct. You mean if(string && string.length<1) {} .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very common to do something like:

```
if (string.length) {
    // string is not nil and the string has a non-zero length
} else {
    // either string is nil or the length is zero
}
```

There is no need, in such a case, to check to see if `string` is `nil` or not.

When `string` is `nil`, you end up doing `[nil length]`. Calling any method on a `nil` pointer results in a value of "zero". How the "zero" is interpreted depends on the method's return type.

Primitive types appear as 0. `BOOL` appears as `NO`. Pointers appear as `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's fine. Your alternate line is harder to understand at a glance and relies on the same logic (nil == 0) as the original line.

Answer (score -1):

Some cases,for example working with strings that are made from response of requests, you should check the string, is a string, and not data!

```
   NSString *string;
if ([string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    //
}
```

Cheers!